# Relations between the trace elements in the cyclic permutations

Tags: linear-algebra

It is well known that the trace is invariant under cyclic permutations, i.e.

$tr(ABCD)=tr(BCDA)=tr(CDAB)=tr(DABC)$ here $A,B,C,$ and $D$ are matrices.

Now, let assume that I define the operator $H1=ABCD$ in the basis $\{a_1,a_2...,a_{n-1},a_n\}$ and $H2=DABC$, what will be the basis of $H2$ with respect to the original basis?. In other words, we know that $tr(H1)=tr(H2)$ but individual elements of the diagonal are not the same i.e. $H1(i,i)\neq H2(i,i)$ but $\sum_{i=1}^n H1(i,i)= \sum_{i=1}^n H2(i,i)$. So, is it possible to find a relation between the elements on the diagonal  of  $H1$ and $H2$ such that if I know  all the diagonal  elements of $H1(i,i)$ I can immediately calculate each element on the diagonal of $H2(i,i)$?

I think there should be a unitary transformation that connect the basis of $H1$ and $H2$ but don not know how to find it!